# Eclipse+html plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin

Is there any HTML tag attribute plug-in for Eclipse

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to install Eclipse Web Tools from Help -> Install new software

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
[EclipseHTMLEditor](http://amateras.sourceforge.jp/cgi-bin/fswiki_en/wiki.cgi?page=EclipseHTMLEditor) and [EclipseTidy](http://eclipsetidy.sourceforge.net/)

Also see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54868/what-is-the-best-html-editor-for-eclipse) for more help on it.